# CMake with Mingw "No rule to make target 'C:/Windows/System32/SDL2.dll'"

Tags: cmake, sdl-2

I'm getting this strange error while trying to build a SDL demo project in CLion.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.1.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\****\.CLion2016.1\system\cmake\generated\teste-62957c9d\62957c9d\Debug --target teste -- -j 4
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** No rule to make target 'C:/Windows/System32/SDL2.dll', needed by 'teste.exe'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/teste.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/teste.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/teste.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [teste] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/teste.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'teste' failed
```

I've tried googling but I didn't find any answer or similar errors relating SDL and mingw. What could be the problem?

I don't know if its of any help, but here is my CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(teste)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(teste ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(teste ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

and an auxiliary .cmake file I use to find SDL2 in my system:

```
# Locate SDL2 library
# This module defines
# SDL2_LIBRARY, the name of the library to link against
# SDL2_FOUND, if false, do not try to link to SDL2
# SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR, where to find SDL.h
#
# This module responds to the the flag:
# SDL2_BUILDING_LIBRARY
# If this is defined, then no SDL2_main will be linked in because
# only applications need main().
# Otherwise, it is assumed you are building an application and this
# module will attempt to locate and set the the proper link flags
# as part of the returned SDL2_LIBRARY variable.
#
# Don't forget to include SDL2main.h and SDL2main.m your project for the
# OS X framework based version. (Other versions link to -lSDL2main which
# this module will try to find on your behalf.) Also for OS X, this
# module will automatically add the -framework Cocoa on your behalf.
#
#
# Additional Note: If you see an empty SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP in your configuration
# and no SDL2_LIBRARY, it means CMake did not find your SDL2 library
# (SDL2.dll, libsdl2.so, SDL2.framework, etc).
# Set SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP to point to your SDL2 library, and configure again.
# Similarly, if you see an empty SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY, you should set this value
# as appropriate. These values are used to generate the final SDL2_LIBRARY
# variable, but when these values are unset, SDL2_LIBRARY does not get created.
#
#
# $SDL2 is an environment variable that would
# correspond to the ./configure --prefix=$SDL2
# used in building SDL2.
# l.e.galup 9-20-02
#
# Modified by Eric Wing.
# Added code to assist with automated building by using environmental variables
# and providing a more controlled/consistent search behavior.
# Added new modifications to recognize OS X frameworks and
# additional Unix paths (FreeBSD, etc).
# Also corrected the header search path to follow "proper" SDL2 guidelines.
# Added a search for SDL2main which is needed by some platforms.
# Added a search for threads which is needed by some platforms.
# Added needed compile switches for MinGW.
#
# On OSX, this will prefer the Framework version (if found) over others.
# People will have to manually change the cache values of
# SDL2_LIBRARY to override this selection or set the CMake environment
# CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH to modify the search paths.
#
# Note that the header path has changed from SDL2/SDL.h to just SDL.h
# This needed to change because "proper" SDL2 convention
# is #include "SDL.h", not <SDL2/SDL.h>. This is done for portability
# reasons because not all systems place things in SDL2/ (see FreeBSD).
#
# Ported by Johnny Patterson. This is a literal port for SDL2 of the FindSDL.cmake
# module with the minor edit of changing "SDL" to "SDL2" where necessary. This
# was not created for redistribution, and exists temporarily pending official
# SDL2 CMake modules.
#
# Note that on windows this will only search for the 32bit libraries, to search
# for 64bit change x86/i686-w64 to x64/x86_64-w64

#=============================================================================
# Copyright 2003-2009 Kitware, Inc.
#
# CMake - Cross Platform Makefile Generator
# Copyright 2000-2014 Kitware, Inc.
# Copyright 2000-2011 Insight Software Consortium
# All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
# are met:
#
# * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
# notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#
# * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
# notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
# documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
#
# * Neither the names of Kitware, Inc., the Insight Software Consortium,
# nor the names of their contributors may be used to endorse or promote
# products derived from this software without specific prior written
# permission.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
# "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
# A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
# HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
# SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
# LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
# DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
# THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
# (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
# OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
#
# This software is distributed WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the
# implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
# See the License for more information.
#=============================================================================
# (To distribute this file outside of CMake, substitute the full
# License text for the above reference.)

FIND_PATH(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR SDL.h
        HINTS
        ${SDL2}
        $ENV{SDL2}
        PATH_SUFFIXES include/SDL2 include SDL2
        i686-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2
        x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/SDL2
        PATHS
        ~/Library/Frameworks
        /Library/Frameworks
        /usr/local/include/SDL2
        /usr/include/SDL2
        /sw # Fink
        /opt/local # DarwinPorts
        /opt/csw # Blastwave
        /opt
        )

# Lookup the 64 bit libs on x64
IF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP SDL2
            HINTS
            ${SDL2}
            $ENV{SDL2}
            PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
            lib/x64
            x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib
            PATHS
            /sw
            /opt/local
            /opt/csw
            /opt
            )
    # On 32bit build find the 32bit libs
ELSE(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP SDL2
            HINTS
            ${SDL2}
            $ENV{SDL2}
            PATH_SUFFIXES lib
            lib/x86
            i686-w64-mingw32/lib
            PATHS
            /sw
            /opt/local
            /opt/csw
            /opt
            )
ENDIF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)

IF(NOT SDL2_BUILDING_LIBRARY)
    IF(NOT ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR} MATCHES ".framework")
        # Non-OS X framework versions expect you to also dynamically link to
        # SDL2main. This is mainly for Windows and OS X. Other (Unix) platforms
        # seem to provide SDL2main for compatibility even though they don't
        # necessarily need it.
        # Lookup the 64 bit libs on x64
        IF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
            FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY
                    NAMES SDL2main
                    HINTS
                    ${SDL2}
                    $ENV{SDL2}
                    PATH_SUFFIXES lib64 lib
                    lib/x64
                    x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib
                    PATHS
                    /sw
                    /opt/local
                    /opt/csw
                    /opt
                    )
            # On 32bit build find the 32bit libs
        ELSE(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
            FIND_LIBRARY(SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY
                    NAMES SDL2main
                    HINTS
                    ${SDL2}
                    $ENV{SDL2}
                    PATH_SUFFIXES lib
                    lib/x86
                    i686-w64-mingw32/lib
                    PATHS
                    /sw
                    /opt/local
                    /opt/csw
                    /opt
                    )
        ENDIF(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    ENDIF(NOT ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR} MATCHES ".framework")
ENDIF(NOT SDL2_BUILDING_LIBRARY)

# SDL2 may require threads on your system.
# The Apple build may not need an explicit flag because one of the
# frameworks may already provide it.
# But for non-OSX systems, I will use the CMake Threads package.
IF(NOT APPLE)
    FIND_PACKAGE(Threads)
ENDIF(NOT APPLE)

# MinGW needs an additional library, mwindows
# It's total link flags should look like -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lmwindows
# (Actually on second look, I think it only needs one of the m* libraries.)
IF(MINGW)
    SET(MINGW32_LIBRARY mingw32 CACHE STRING "mwindows for MinGW")
ENDIF(MINGW)

SET(SDL2_FOUND "NO")
IF(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP)
    # For SDL2main
    IF(NOT SDL2_BUILDING_LIBRARY)
        IF(SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY)
            SET(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP ${SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP})
        ENDIF(SDL2MAIN_LIBRARY)
    ENDIF(NOT SDL2_BUILDING_LIBRARY)

    # For OS X, SDL2 uses Cocoa as a backend so it must link to Cocoa.
    # CMake doesn't display the -framework Cocoa string in the UI even
    # though it actually is there if I modify a pre-used variable.
    # I think it has something to do with the CACHE STRING.
    # So I use a temporary variable until the end so I can set the
    # "real" variable in one-shot.
    IF(APPLE)
        SET(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP ${SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP} "-framework Cocoa")
    ENDIF(APPLE)

    # For threads, as mentioned Apple doesn't need this.
    # In fact, there seems to be a problem if I used the Threads package
    # and try using this line, so I'm just skipping it entirely for OS X.
    IF(NOT APPLE)
        SET(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP ${SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
    ENDIF(NOT APPLE)

    # For MinGW library
    IF(MINGW)
        SET(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP ${MINGW32_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP})
    ENDIF(MINGW)

    # Set the final string here so the GUI reflects the final state.
    SET(SDL2_LIBRARY ${SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP} CACHE STRING "Where the SDL2 Library can be found")
    # Set the temp variable to INTERNAL so it is not seen in the CMake GUI
    SET(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP "${SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP}" CACHE INTERNAL "")

    SET(SDL2_FOUND "YES")
ENDIF(SDL2_LIBRARY_TEMP)

INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(SDL2 REQUIRED_VARS SDL2_LIBRARY SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

**Update**

After a reconfiguration of the project, as @Tsyvarev pointed out, the error was gone and now I have this `undefined reference to SDL_main` errors:

```
 C:/SDL2/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libSDL2main.a(SDL_windows_main.o): In function `main_utf8':
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:126: undefined reference to `SDL_main'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:126: undefined reference to `SDL_main'
/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.4-source/foo-x86/../src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:126: undefined reference to `SDL_main'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [SDLDemo.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SDLDemo.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\SDLDemo.dir\build.make:98: recipe for target 'SDLDemo.exe' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SDLDemo.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SDLDemo.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [SDLDemo] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SDLDemo.dir/rule' failed
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'SDLDemo' failed
```

**Update 2:**

A simple change from `int main(){...}` to `int main(int argc, char *argv[]){...}` in my main source code file solved the problem..

Comment: Does file *C:/Windows/System32/SDL2.dll* exist on your machine? (Ignore slash usage on Windows for the first time).

Comment: Yes.. I was having a "SDL2.dll invalid format" error before, so I removed it from System32 and put it again (making sure It was the 32 bit file), and now I have this "no rule to make.." error I describe in the question.. @Tsyvarev

Comment: Did you tried to reconfigure project *clearly* (that is, with empty cache)? After manipulations with library files clean reconfigure has a sence.

Comment: I did just now and it worked.. However, I have some undefined reference's to SDL_main errors now. Could you help me? I just edited the question. @Tsyvarev

Comment: never mind, just solved it. @Tsyvarev